# Sitefinity personalization by Time of Day not working on IIS

Tags: c#, content-management-system, personalization, sitefinity-10, sitefinity-feather

I need the personalised version of Content block in the Sitefinity CMS, I have created different segment for the "Time of Day" and it is working on visual studio debug mode when I am going to deploy the code on IIS server it is not working, any solution for this would be highly appreciated

Thanks :)

Comment: Timezones are set correctly in the Sitefinity settings? How about the View Site As functionality - does it work correctly ?

Comment: Yes I have checked the timezone is set correctly in the Sitefinity settings!